# matplotlib quiver weird plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make simple quiver plot, with 4 points in xy plane which roughly form square, and 4 shifted points which form smaller, inner square. But my arrows are weird.
What am I doing wrong?

```
p_x = np.array([1,10,10,1]).reshape(-1,1)
p_y = np.array([1,1,10,10]).reshape(-1,1)
corr_x = np.array([2,9,9,2]).reshape(-1,1)
corr_y = np.array([2,2,9,9]).reshape(-1,1)
```

[image]

And this is what I got with quiver with the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ax.quiver(p_x, p_y, corr_x, corr_y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.
According to the documentation, the second coordinates in the quiver - U and V are directions, but, relative to the first coordinates, X and Y. U and V are not endpoints. If you want vectors to end at some specific coordinates, then you need to give the quiver, the endpoints like this:
U = U - X and V = V - Y.
In the example below, my first vector starts at (0,0) and ends at (2,2) and the second vector starts at (2,2) and ends at (3,0). But if I try to plot it like that, with the code below:

```
X = np.array([0, 2])
Y = np.array([0, 2])
U = np.array([2, 3])
V = np.array([2, 0])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid()
plt.xlim(-2,8)
plt.ylim(-1,5)
plt.show()
```

I got the following plot.

[image]

Therefore, to end the vector at the coordinates I want, I need to make adjustement, like this:
U = U - X
V = V - Y.

And the following plot is the plot I needed.

[image]